# Ruby ZipFile.extract is not preserving the permissions

Tags: ruby

I have written a Ruby method to unzip the zip file (as per the requirements I am not suppose to use shell `unzip` command). But it is not preserving the permissions. There are lots of file (the zipfile is pretty big) so I don't want to update the permissions manually. Can someone kindly help me in fixing this issue?

Below is the piece of code that unzips the build.

```
 def unzip_file (file_path, destination_path)
            begin
               Zip::ZipFile.open(file_path) { |zip_file| zip_file.each { |f|

                                               f_path=File.join(destination_path, f.name)

                                               FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(f_path))

                                               zip_file.extract(f, f_path) unless File.exist?(f_path)
                                             }
                                           }
            rescue => e
                    $LOG.error "Error occurred in Utils.unzip_file - #{e}"
            end
       end
```

Comment: The standard indentation in Ruby is 2 spaces, not 3, not 8, not 11, and certainly not 32.

Answer (score 2):

The `zip` gem does not restore permissions by default. You must set the `restore_permissions` attribute to true on the `ZipFile` object before extracting its entries. So, use this:

```
Zip::ZipFile.open(file_path) do |zip_file|
  zip_file.restore_permissions = true
  zip_file.each do |f|
    # ...
  end
end
```

There is also a `restore_ownership` attribute you can set, if you want to restore ownership too.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working piece of code which will unzip the zipfile and preserve permissions.

```
def unzip_file (file_path, destination_path)
   begin
      Zip::ZipFile.open(file_path) { |zip_file|  
                                      zip_file.restore_permissions = true
                                      zip_file.each { |f|
                                           f_path=File.join(destination_path, f.name)
                                           FleUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(f_path))
                                           zip_file.extract(f, f_path) unless File.exist?(f_path)
                                         }
                                    }
    rescue => e
             $LOG.error "Error occurred in Utils.unzip_file - #{e}"
     end
 end
```